# how to set current date in application in android without datepicker.please tell me how to write code

Tags: android

```
package com.example.productstock;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoriesActivity extends Activity {
TextView t1;
Button b1;
TextView date;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categories);

    t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   

    Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    dt.clear();
    dt.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); 

    return;

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i1=new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this,BoxesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

});
```

Comment: only date as to display every day i open it.not same date

Answer (score 0):

input this

```
   import java.util.Calendar;
   import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
```

and get date from this

```
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   //check the time as is it in "AM" OR "PM" 
   String am_pm = (cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)?"AM":"PM";

    //you can get year 
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    //you can get month
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    //we must add 1 to the month because Calendar.MONTH start from 0

    //you can get day
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //you can get time
    String time =cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

So all together cord is like this

```
   String DateTime =" Date  "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"        Time  "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" : "+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" : "+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)+" "+am_pm +"";
```

so i think you get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            //Get the string values e.g
    String yearStr = Integer.toString(year);
            //Finally, concatinate your string monthStr+" "dayStr+", "yearStr
```